# How can you change product's position in category as per store view

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Is their any way to change the product's position in category to set as per store view ?

Any module available which can handle this stuff, as I am sure this is global change by default in magento.

[image: check image for more details]

Comment: you can create a field in catalog_category_product called store_id , and save the value of store if when product assign to category ,

then in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product

in collection add joinField store_id same like "product_id=entity_id" and check

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible.

Category entity has attribute 'position' which is actually static (it means that the attribute is in the main catalog_category_entity table). Also we have 'path' column in the main table for defining categories relation.

This two column is the base for category position.

About attributes: Did you tried to change values per attribute in the catalog_eav_attribute? Column 'position' in this table used for layered navigation on the frontend (but this attribute is deprecated).

So, on my point of view only with customization we can change this logic.

Comment: I am talking about position of products in categories and not about position of categories.

Comment: How to set a position for a shop by attribute on the category website page? @Dhaval Patel